# How to extract 1 or 2 words before n digits?

Tags: r, regex

I've this sample data frame:

```
address <- c("11537 W LARKSPUR RD EL MIRAGE 85335", "6702 E CPT DREYFUS SCOTTSDALE 85254", "114 S PUEBLO ST GILBERT 85233", "16981 W YOUNG ST SURPRISE 85388")
person <- c("Maria", "Jose", "Adan", "Eva")

my_address <- tibble(person, address)
```

I need to extract the `city` from the `address` column. The City could consist of 1 word or 2, but they are always before the ZIP CODE that consist of ***5 digits***.

> From the data frame, I would like to get: "EL MIRAGE", "SCOTTSDALE" and "GILBERT" in a new column: `city`

**Important:**

The cities are always after a 2 or 3 letter word like: ST, AVE, RD.

For example, from: "16981 W YOUNG ST SURPRISE 85388". I'd like to get SURPRISE that is after "ST".

So,  I was trying this regex:

```
my_address$city <-gsub("(.*)([a-zA-Z])([0-9]{5})(.*)", "\\2", my_address$address)
```

But it return all the text in the column, not the desired cities. Also, I notice that I didn't instruct it to check for 1 or 2 words before 5 digits, so It would extract only 1 word?

**UPDATE 1:**

```
string1 <- "114 S PUEBLO ST GILBERT 85233"
sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(string1,"\\w{4,}"),"[",3)
```

returns: `85233`, when `GILBERT`  was expected.

Comment: Why not DREYFUS SCOTTDALE?

Comment: @NelsonGon Dreyfus is the AVE and SCOTTDALE the City.

Comment: @NelsonGon Also the words before city are always of length 2 or 3 ("RD", "ST", "AVE". I think this could help in the regex. You answer returns "MIRAGE" when "EL MIRAGE" is needed.

Comment: Your current requirements result in `\b\p{L}{2,3}\s+((?:\p{L}+\s+)?\p{L}+)\s+\d{5}\b` regex, see https://regex101.com/r/zHTjX6/1. `CPT` before `DREYFUS` is 3 char long.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew cannot use this in gsub. Got: '\p' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\b\p"

Comment: You say "The cities are always after a 2 or 3 letter word like: ST, AVE, RD.", but the second address-entry is: `"6702 E CPT DREYFUS SCOTTSDALE 85254"`... No 2-3 letter word before SCOTTSDALE ?

Comment: I know this doesn't follow the rule, but just need "SCOTTSDALE".

Comment: @OmarGonzales What `gsub`? It should be used like `str_match(my_address$address,"\\b\\p{L}{2,3}\\s+((?:\\p{L}+\\s+)?\\p{L}+)\\s+\\d{5}\\b")[,2]`. But it is not the point. The point is that your requirements mean that you expect `DREYFUS SCOTTSDALE` from `6702 E CPT DREYFUS SCOTTSDALE 85254`. If you do not have a 100% rule here, it means you **cannot use regular language** and there is no solution. "I want this" is not a programming requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dplyr+stringr / tidyverse solution is based on the fact that you know what 2-3 letter words preceed a city...

```
# vector with  2-3 letter words before a city?
v.before <- c("ST", "RD", "AVE")
#with this vector, we can build an 'or'-pattern for a regex    

library( dplyr )
library( stringr )
data.frame( person, address) %>% 
  mutate( place = stringr::str_extract( address, paste0("(?<=", paste0(v.before, collapse = " |" ), " ).*(?= [0-9]{5})") ) ) %>%
  #no match found?, then the city is the second last word from address
  mutate( place = ifelse( is.na( place ), stringr::word(address, -2), place))

#   person                             address      place
# 1  Maria 11537 W LARKSPUR RD EL MIRAGE 85335  EL MIRAGE
# 2   Jose 6702 E CPT DREYFUS SCOTTSDALE 85254 SCOTTSDALE
# 3   Adan       114 S PUEBLO ST GILBERT 85233    GILBERT
# 4    Eva     16981 W YOUNG ST SURPRISE 85388   SURPRISE
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally prefer one liners although this seems overly complicated and will require another step to remove "ST" before "SURPRISE". It has been done here assuming everything starts with "ST".

```
 library(stringr)
 new_s<-unlist(str_extract_all(my_address$address,"\\w{2,} \\w{3,}"))
 newer_s<-str_remove_all(new_s,"^\\w{3}.*\\D$")
 newer_s<-str_remove_all(newer_s,"\\s.*\\d")
 res<-str_remove_all(newer_s,"^ST ")
 res[res==""]<-NA 
 my_address$city<-res[complete.cases(res)]
```

Result:

```
 my_address
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  person address                             city      
#  <chr>  <chr>                               <chr>     
#1 Maria  11537 W LARKSPUR RD EL MIRAGE 85335 EL MIRAGE 
#2 Jose   6702 E CPT DREYFUS SCOTTSDALE 85254 SCOTTSDALE
#3 Peter  16981 W YOUNG ST SURPRISE 85388     SURPRISE  
#4 Paul   114 S PUEBLO ST GILBERT 85233       GILBERT
```

Data:

```
address <- c("11537 W LARKSPUR RD EL MIRAGE 85335", "6702 E CPT DREYFUS SCOTTSDALE 85254",
             "16981 W YOUNG ST SURPRISE 85388","114 S PUEBLO ST GILBERT 85233")
person <- c("Maria", "Jose","Peter","Paul")

my_address <- tibble::tibble(person, address)
```

Comment: I've added another less efficient answer. Perhaps someone else has a more elegant solution.

Comment: @OmarGonzales Edited. For future users. Might need to remove multiple avenues like in the accepted answer. I only removed ST here.